# Java - Reusing scalar methods on arrays of same objects

Tags: java, vectorization

Say there is a method `Operation`,

```
public ObjectOut Operation(ObjectIn input)
```

What is the best way to apply the operation method to an ObjectIn[] object?
Do you need to explicitely overload `Operation`,

```
public ObjectOut[] Operation(ObjectIn[] input) {
    ObjectOut[] output = new ObjectOut[input.length];

    for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++)
        output[i] = Operation(input[i]);
}
```

Or is there a more generic way of doing this **once** for all such "scalar" methods?

Comment: In Java I think that's the only simple solution. A really dynamic solution would be a groovy implementation where you can define closures for that and make dynamic (non statically linked) method calls even with strings as method-name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an approach like this:

```
public class Scalar {

    interface ScalarMethod<T, O> { O apply(T input); }

    public static<T, O> O[] scalar(T[] array, O[] result, ScalarMethod<T, O> method) {

        for ( int i=0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
            result[i] = method.apply(array[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = new String[] { "Hello", ", world!" };

        Integer[] result = Scalar.scalar(input, 
                                         new Integer[input.length],
                                         new ScalarMethod<String, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer apply(String input) {
                System.out.println(input);
                return input.length();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here you define the behaviour of the scalar from outside and apply the behaviour to each array item. But how the items are iterated is not relevant to the caller. (Tell don't ask)

That way you don't duplicate the code of the loop that iterates over the items. And you are flexible enough to add various types of scalar methods.

Edit: I added a second generic parameter for the result like Fabian suggested. This makes the method more flexible. I also removed the casting of the array (which was wrong in the first place).

Comment: This is what Google Guava does with its transform methods and functions. :)

Comment: Cool! Then it just depends if you want to use Guava or code everything yourself. I'd certainly use Guava, since I'm lazy. +1 for Guava :-)

Comment: I've forgotten to +1 for a totally valid solution. Here you are. ;) Making use of generics like Guava does would further improve your solution.

Comment: Very good suggestion, it seems much nicer to use now. I added it to the solution, but I don't know how to get rid of the ugly cast in the return statement.

Comment: I am sorry, but now it is broken. :-/ You need 2 types for your function since the input type may differ from the output type.

Comment: Seems like it could work, and no need to obtain external libraries. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s `Lists.transform()` for this purpose.

```
List<ObjectOut> output = Lists.transform(
      new ArrayList<ObjectIn>() // your input list
  ,   new Function<ObjectIn, ObjectOut>() {
            @Override
            public ObjectOut apply(ObjectIn input) {
                // process your input
                return null;
            }
      } 
);
```

There also exist `Collections2.transform()` for Collections and `Iterables.transform()` for Iterables. You should be aware that the returned list is a view. You may want to create a copy of it before go on working with it. Be sure to check documentation.

But before using this you should know about the [downsides](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Caveats) as @LouisWasserman pointed out.

Comment: That said, Guava's [policy](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained#Caveats) is that this is overkill for most cases, and the traditional, `for`-based solution is more readable and more efficient most of the time.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You're right. At least readability can be dramatically improved when you have function singletons. Then these transforms become a very short, readable one-liner without that anonymous function classes. Nevertheless your link is valueable to read and follow.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is no generic way to accomplish this.

There are however very clean ways.

You could create a wrapper class that contains your array of ObjectIn objects, and provides whatever methods you need, eg;

```
public class ObjectInArray {
    ObjectIn[] objects;
    public ObjectOut[] OperationAll() {
        ObjectOut[] output = new ObjectOut[objects.length];
        for(int i=0; i<objects.length; i++) output[i] = ObjectIn.operation();
        return output;
    }
}
```